# Calculate cross correlation coefficients matrix between several 1-D arrays

Tags: python, matrix

I have several 1-D arrays (say seven 1-D arrays). I need to calculate cross correlation coefficients between each other (7 x 7). Is there any tricky way to do it in Python? Thank you all.

I expected to get a 7x7 symmetric matrix as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

Probably not the optimal solution but it works:

```py
import numpy as np

arrays = [
    np.array([1, 2, 3]),
    np.array([3, 4, 5]),
    np.array([6, 7, 8])
]

n = len(arrays)

correlation_matrix = np.zeros((n, n))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        correlation_matrix[i, j] = np.correlate(arrays[i], arrays[j])

print(correlation_matrix)
```

Output

```
[[ 14.  26.  44.]
 [ 26.  50.  86.]
 [ 44.  86. 149.]]
```

Used three arrays as an example, but should work with as many as you fit into the `arrays` variable.